# In Android with opencv, to convert BitmapToMat is efficient way to convert mat image or any other possibilities to convert Mat image?

Tags: android, c++, opencv, native

I was converting BitmapToMat image using opencv android. While i pass a Mat image to Native code (c++) from android, Image channels become changed. 
Directly we pass Mat image without conversion(bitmaptomat), image channels remains unchanged.

Is there anyother Efficient way to pass image from android to native c++. 
Is there any possibilities using OpenGL ES..
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by passing to C++ the bytes of your Bitmap directly :
In java :
    Declare your native method

```
public native void bmpToJNI(byte[] myArray);

Bitmap bmp;
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
```

In C++ file, declaration of the method :

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_your_package_your_activity_bmpToJNI( JNIEnv* env,jobject thiz, jbyteArrayarray) {...}
```

Nervertheless, can you precise the way the channels are changed ?

Comment: In client server communication byte array is efficient way to pass. Please justify...